# Making a 2D map with "physical objects" in C#

Tags: c#, xml, image, winforms, 2d

I wanted to make a 2D map in C# with physical objects using coordinates and xml. Xml would be parsed and things from there should be "mapped" on a rectancular in a Form.

For example:

```
<chair>
  <x>12</x>
  <y>20</y>
</chair>
```

would put an image of a chair in (12,20) in a rectangle on a Form.

Is my XML approach even sane? I want to accomplish it with or without XML, I just don't have any other good and easy idea.

In other words:
On my Form, I have an area, let's call it a "room".
I parse XML and find out that a chair should be on (12,20) in this room.
How can I put an image of a chair in that place in my "room"?
I want to be able to make something like a 2D map of these objects in a room.

How can I do such things in C# Windows Forms?

Comment: look into making xsd files and xsd2code from there serialization and xml parsing. I think your approach is fine. you just need to build some infrastructure

Comment: Is the approach *sane*, yes. It will just require some good design. This seems a bit broad, can you narrow it to a question about that design; perhaps show what you have and isn't working?

Comment: Serialization is really useful, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you have here may fall under a fairly common CAD/CAM software software design pattern.  In AutoCAD this is the "[Block/Insert](http://docs.autodesk.com/ACD/2010/ENU/AutoCAD%202010%20User%20Documentation/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ffa23ce210c4a30acaf-6c3e.htm,topicNumber=d0e80293)" pattern:

[image]

In Revit, it's the "[Family](http://docs.autodesk.com/REVIT/2010/ENU/Revit%20Architecture%202010%20Users%20Guide/RAC/index.html?url=WS73099cc142f487557cb2baea11cffb8adb7-5e6a.htm,topicNumber=d0e32443)/[Instance](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2011/01/newfamilyinstance-overloads.html)" pattern.  In Pro/ENGINEER, it's something like "[Model/Assembly Component](http://www.ncsu.edu/project/graphicscourse/gc/proetut/assemble.html)".  The basic idea is that the user may insert (a/k/a instantiate a/k/a assemble) some external design object, defined in its own design space (possibly in the same file, or a different file), with some specified transformation from the external space to their top level design space.  The object then appears in the top level design space, but it's not copied -- it's linked.  Changes to the external object are reflected by all insertions of the object.

(I don't know whether the [software design patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) community has a standard name for this pattern.  It's common throughout CAD though.)

Thus, since you are following a common pattern, I think you're on a reasonable track.  Your XML entities correspond to a sequence of block insertions adding standard library objects into the top level design space of the user's Form.

I would suggest one change to your design.  Your current XML design has a separate class for each type of standard object that can be inserted, i.e.:

```
<chair>
    <!-- Placement information  -->
</chair>
<table>
    <!-- Placement information  -->
</table>
```

I might suggest defining a general-purpose insertion entity, e.g.:

```
<insert DefinitionObject="some-unique-identifier">
    <!-- Placement information  -->
</insert>
```

This will allow you to easily add new types of standard objects to insert without needing to define lots of new insertion classes.